# 414 Request-URI Too Large ошибка. API Python

Tags: python, api, post, get

Решил в качестве развития, написать простенький код который поможет загружать мне фото-файлы на ImgBB. При использовании base64 (требование), оно выдает ошибку. Я думал что ошибка в POST|GET запросах, но вроде все правильно. Тем не менее выдает ошибку 414. Можете чем-то подсобить?

```
import requests
import base64

res = requests.get('https://imgbb.com/')
print(res.status_code)

API_KEY = 'bbb346b8fda3393ca60bdb1ba16fd8cf'
url = 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload'
img = base64.b64encode(open("image.png", "rb").read())

params = dict(key=API_KEY, image=img)
res = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(res.text)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не используй get запрос.  Длина URL ограничена (в среднем 1-2 тыс. символов). Ты же пытаешься в него засунуть мегадлинную строку  base64. Передавай картинку через post параметры.

Comment: Здесь дан пример такого post запроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295813/how-to-post-image-in-imgbb-com-via-python

Answer (score 0):

А теперь открываем документацию и сервиса и читаем:

> API v1 calls can be done using the POST or GET request methods but
> since GET request are limited by the maximum allowed length of an URL
> you should prefer the POST request method

Вызовы API v1 могут быть выполнены с помощью методов запроса POST или GET, но поскольку запрос GET ограничен максимально допустимой длиной URL, вам следует предпочесть метод запроса POST.

> Note: Always use POST when uploading local files. Url encoding may
> alter the base64 source due to encoded characters or just by URL
> request length limit due to GET request.

Примечание: Всегда используйте POST при загрузке локальных файлов. Кодировка Url может изменять источник base64 из-за кодированных символов или просто из-за ограничения длины URL в GET запросе.